I need help identifying an SMD filter marked “46D t7W”


This is an EPCOS filter, makr 46D t7W, package is smd5 1.4mmx1.1mm
I can not find the pdf

Need dimensions and pins of part

It is a SAW filter from RF360 Europe (Qualcomm + TDK previously EPCOS...)
And according to the marking "46D", it is a B4301 type:



46D translation:
4 *32^2 + 6 *32 + 13(=D) = 4301

And then when I search "RF360 B4301", the only part number I find is B39921B4301F210 which is a 915 MHz SAW filter.
typical marking style (mouser):

